# XAMPP Apache & MySQL Server won't start

Tags: mysql, apache, service, xampp

aI have the problem that both services won't start. On both, I get the Message

`Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.` (The same with apache).

I already changed the ports of the apache server from 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4433, and also to others to check, that doesn't help.

I tried some solutions on similar posts here, like deleting the ibdata1-file in the mysql-folder, but none of these seem to work. I even don't think these might solve it, because both services are affected.

Another idea I had was that I had not enough rights on the pc to run these services, but I am logged in as administrator and I also have a postgres-service running which I am able to stop and restart.

I am using Windows 10, but had XAMPP running on it before.

Logfile: Apache

```
[Wed Jan 13 09:33:31.539128 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5664:tid 572] AH00098: pid file D:/Data/Xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jan 13 09:33:32.039157 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5664:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 13 09:33:32.039157 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5664:tid 572] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Jan 13 09:33:32.039157 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5664:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\data\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/Data/Xampp/apache'
[Wed Jan 13 09:33:32.039157 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5664:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4376
[Wed Jan 13 09:33:32.523560 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4376:tid 556] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Logfile: MySQL

```
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-01-13 09:33:33 af8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 61260762 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-01-13 09:33:33 5760 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 61260762
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-01-13 09:33:34 5760 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

If I select the xampp-start.exe, I get this message in the cmd-window:

```
2016-01-14 10:30:28 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-01-14 10:30:28 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-01-14 10:30:28 0 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.6.24) starting as process 1800 ...
2016-01-14 10:30:28 1800 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile 'D:\Data\Xampp\mysql\share\errmsg.sys'
2016-01-14 10:30:28 1800 [Warning] Can't create test file D:\Data\Xampp\mysql\data\DESKTOP-0E1SMUM.lower-test
2016-01-14 10:30:28 1800 [Warning] Can't create test file D:\Data\Xampp\mysql\data\DESKTOP-0E1SMUM.lower-test
mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Can't change dir to 'D:\Data\Xampp\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2016-01-14 10:30:28 1800 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-01-14 10:30:28 1800 [Note] Binlog end
2016-01-14 10:30:28 1800 [Note]
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 37 of E:/Data/Xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory
```

The File errmsg.sys exists though.

Comment: Look in the Windows Event Viewer for messages from Apache and MYSQL. They write there before opening their individual error log.

Comment: Those logs do not cover a complete startup. Make sure you include from the termination of the previous startup upto the last line in the log

Comment: @RiggsFolly that are the whole error-logs, there is no more. If I reproduce the error there are no new lines added

Comment: Any luck with this issue? Keen to know how you solved it

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that worked for me!
If anyone has that problem, try to start apache via batch file "apache_start" located in xampp-directory. that gave me the error:

`ServerRoot must be a valid directory`

This again could be solved by running the "setup_xampp" batch file, located in the same directory. After completion, apache & mysql were running again.